# iPad - Show/Hide UIBarButton

Tags: iphone, ipad, uibarbuttonitem

Is there a way to hide or show a UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: We can hide navigation item by setting its property to nil and whenever we want to show it then we can just write in condition so that we can display button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USe this to hide barbutton item.

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;

Answer (score 2):

Actually, UIBarButtonItem does not respond to .hidden.  It is not a subclass of UIButton.

Here is a quick example of how you can switch three buttons a left button a middle button and a right button.

//So, in the proper place

```
IBOutlet UIToolbar *bottomToolbar;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *leftButton;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *flexerSpace;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *middleButton;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *rightButton;
```

//Then this in the proper place

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *bottomToolbar;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *leftButton;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *flexerSpace;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *middleButton;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *rightButton;
```

//Then in the proper place

```
@synthesize bottomToolbar;
@synthesize leftButton;
@synthesize flexerSpace;
@synthesize middleButton;
@synthesize rightButton;
```

then reload your class in IB or Xcode4 IB in your nib

// then in your

view_switcher/controller methods

```
-(IBAction)switchToLeft:(id)sender {

NSArray *newButtonArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: middleButton, flexerSpace, rightButton, nil];

[bottomToolbar setItems:newButtonArray animated:NO]; //YES or NO either way it
}

-(IBAction)switchToMiddle:(id)sender {

NSArray *newButtonArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: leftButton, flexerSpace, rightButton, nil];

[bottomToolbar setItems:newButtonArray animated:NO]; //YES or NO either way it
}

-(IBAction)switchToRight:(id)sender {

NSArray *newButtonArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: leftButton, flexerSpace, middleButton, nil];

[bottomToolbar setItems:newButtonArray animated:NO]; //YES or NO either way it
}
```

then connect the buttons and add your view switching, this should do it ...

Assuming you can fill in some parts

Answer (score 1):

This is my UIBarButtonItem subclass to expose a setHidden method. I use it whenever I have an "optional" button on my bars.
It works for textual or image buttons.

```
class AltoUIBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {

var originalImage : UIImage?
var originalTitle : String?

override func awakeFromNib() {

    originalTitle = self.title
    originalImage = self.image
}

func setHidden(_ hidden: Bool)
{
    if hidden
    {
        if originalImage != nil { self.image = nil}
        if originalTitle != nil { self.title = ""}
        self.isEnabled = false
    }
    else
    {
        if originalImage != nil { self.image = originalImage}
        if originalTitle != nil { self.title = originalTitle}
        self.isEnabled = true
    }
}

func setOriginalTitle(_ originalTitle: String?)
{
    self.originalTitle = originalTitle
}
```

}